# ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied on Pluggable database

Tags: oracle12c, pdb, cdb, ora-01017, oracle19c

I created a local user under a pluggable database. I granted some privileges required to open and use it. I check the username and the password. Still it keep saying invalid username/password.

Step that I take:

```
1. alter session set container = xxxxpdb
2. alter pluggable database xxxpdb open
3. SQL> alter user #### identified by #### container = current;  

User altered.        -----i did this one to make sure that i have a correct password

4. connect ###/###@XXXXpdb;
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

5. Then tried to connect to it this way 
$ sqlplus ###/###@xxxxpdb

ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

I am new to container database. I would appreciate any detailed explanation! Thank you.

Comment: Your user have create session privilege in xxxpdb ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on error message, it looks like the user doesn't exist in PDB.

For an existing user you may get a relevant error related to privilege. For example:

```
SQL> conn <existing_uname_without_required_privileges>/<upass>@<pdb_name>
ERROR:
ORA-01045: user <uname> lacks CREATE SESSION privilege; logon denied


Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.
SQL>
```

For a non-existing user, the error you have observed will be returned:

```
SQL> conn <non_existing_user>/<upass>@<pdb_name>
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied


SQL>
```

This [OraDoc Page](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/multi/overview-of-the-multitenant-architecture.html#GUID-44E8518A-E02C-429C-9B06-16078EB3251A) provides the local user related information in CDB.